# 'libpng error: Read Error' by using open cv imread

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, libpng, imread

I am currently using Anaconda 4.3.27, Python 3.6.2 and OpenCV 3.3.0

When I try

```
img1 = cv2.imread('D:\Images\3D-Matplotlib.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('D:\Images\mainsvmimage.png')
```

I get `libpng error: Read Error`and a pop-up shows up, indicating that Python stopped working. I already tried replacing the '\' by '\\' and '/', but also in those cases the same error shows up. When I try to read a jpg instead of a png, I do not get the error. Does anybody have an idea what might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Also cv2.imwrite gives an error:

```
libpng error: Write Error
```

Comment: do the images exist with given path? may be you can try os.listdir("D:/Images/")

Comment: Yeah they are. When I try os.listdir, they are returned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue with Anaconda using Matplotlib with Latex. The solution was to update libpng. 
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6271

Answer (score 1):

I had broken images in my directory, removing those images solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the flags (grayscale,...) that are required by `cv2.imread` ( https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html )

and use `r` for the path

```
 img2 = cv2.imread(r"D:\Images\mainsvmimage.png",0)
```

( the `0` loads image as grayscale )

[OpenCV Python not opening images with imread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564889/opencv-python-not-opening-images-with-imread)

if this is still not working maybe test with another image as it is possible that there is a problem with the image header cf. [libpng error: Read Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530591/libpng-error-read-error?rq=1) or with your `libpng` version, cf. [Libpng conflict on OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865389/libpng-conflict-on-opencv)

Comment: Adding a flag and using 'r' in front of the path doesn't work. I tried saving the jpg that I could open as an png, but when I try reading it with imread, I get the same error. If the problem would be caused by the libpng version, shouldn't I be getting a different error like in the 'Libpng conflict on OpenCV?'-link?

Comment: can you open a `.jpg` with `img2 = cv2.imread(r"D:\Images\jpg_image.jpg.",0)` ? normally this should work and if it works the problem is either related to `libpng` or with the headers of your pngs or permission problems, normally the python code above is correct

Comment: Yes, I can open a .jpg. I now tried to update conda and libpng, but I still got the same error after it was updated. Is there a way to narrow down where my error is coming from? I'm still quite new to Python and OpenCV, so I don't have that much experience yet.

Comment: i don't know, very likely this is `libpng` error and i am not familiar with windows. the `libpng` version has to match the version of `opencv`.  if you are not fixed to `.png` use `.jpg` files and skip the libpng bug tracking. from matplotlib you can save files as `.jpg` like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827016/matplotlib-savefig-in-jpeg-format

Comment: Yeah, for now I'm going to circumvent the problem by using only .jpg. Hopefully somewhere in the future it will become clear what the problem is. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I had a similar issue when trying to read images with OpenCV imread() function.

The solution was to "clean" the path.

There were spaces and "+" in the filepath, and by replacing both with "_" the files are now properly read by cv2.imread().